# How to use a window function to count day of week occurrences in Pyspark 2.1

Tags: pyspark, window, apache-spark-2.1.1

With the below pyspark dataset (2.1), how to you use a windowing function that would count the number of times the current record's day of week appeared int he last 28 days.

Example Data frame:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("a", "1", "2018-01-01 12:01:01","Monday"),
        ("a", "13", "2018-01-01 14:01:01","Monday"),
        ("a", "22", "2018-01-02 22:01:01","Tuesday"),
        ("a", "43", "2018-01-08 01:01:01","Monday"),
        ("a", "43", "2018-01-09 01:01:01","Tuesday"),
        ("a", "74", "2018-01-10 12:01:01","Wednesday"),
        ("a", "95", "2018-01-15 06:01:01","Monday"),
], ["person_id", "other_id", "timestamp","dow"])


df.withColumn("dow_count",`some window function`)
```

Possible window

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
Days_28 = (86400 * 28)
window= Window.partitionBy("person_id").orderBy('timestamp').rangeBetween(-Days_30, -1)
## I know this next line is wrong
df.withColumn("dow_count",F.sum(F.when(Current_day=windowed_day,1).otherwise(0)).over(window))
```

Example Output

```
df.show()

+---------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+
|person_id|other_id|          timestamp|      dow|dow_count|
+---------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+
|        a|       1|2018-01-01 12:01:01|   Monday|0        |
|        a|      13|2018-01-01 14:01:01|   Monday|1        |
|        a|      22|2018-01-02 22:01:01|  Tuesday|0        |
|        a|      43|2018-01-08 01:01:01|   Monday|2        |
|        a|      43|2018-01-09 01:01:01|  Tuesday|1        |
|        a|      74|2018-01-10 12:01:01|Wednesday|0        |
|        a|      95|2018-01-15 06:01:01|   Monday|3        |
+---------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Use F.row_number(), window partitioned by (person_id, dow) and the logic with your `rangeBetween()` should be replaced with `where()`:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

N_days = 28
end = datetime.combine(datetime.today(), datetime.min.time())
start = end - timedelta(days=N_days)

window = Window.partitionBy("person_id", "dow").orderBy('timestamp')

df.where((df.timestamp < end) & (df.timestamp >= start)) \
  .withColumn('dow_count', F.row_number().over(window)-1) \
  .show()
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it compares the date in each row to the current timestamp instead of taking each row and counting back 28 days.

Comment: but each row can only save one `dow_count`, unless you add 27 more columns or rows in your dataframe. is this what you want?

Comment: Ah, I see, you were putting a column for each day of week. yeah, each row only needs dow_count, specifically the day of week that it is currently. So if the current day is a Monday, then I only need dow_count for mondays in the last 28 days.

Comment: I got it now. The partitioning by "dow" helped a lot. I ended up creating a unix_ts, casting it as an long and using a count over a window.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and thought I'd share.

First create a unix timestamp and cast it to long.
Then, partition by person and day of week.
Finally, use the count function over the window.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('unix_ts',df.timestamp.astype('Timestamp').cast("long"))

w = Window.partitionBy('person_id','dow').orderBy('unix_ts').rangeBetween(-86400*15,-1)
df = df.withColumn('occurrences_in_7_days',F.count('unix_ts').over(w))
df.sort(df.unix_ts).show()
```

Bonus: How to create the actual day of week from the timestamp.

```
df = df.withColumn("DayOfWeek",F.date_format(df.timestamp, 'EEEE'))
```

I couldn't have done it without tips from jxc and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531662/pyspark-how-to-use-lag-and-rangebetween-functions-on-timestamp-values) stackoverflow article.